# react native textInputs wrap on iOS

Tags: react-native

My react native textInputs wrap on iOS. I want them to not wrap, and have overflow hidden.

Code:

```
  textInput: {
    flex: 1,
    whiteSpace: 'nowrap',
    overflow: 'hidden',
    textOverflow: 'ellipsis',
    lineHeight: 20,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    width: '100%',
    fontWeight: '200',
    fontSize: 17,
    paddingLeft: 15,
    paddingRight: 15,
    color: '#7c6a4d',
    backgroundColor: '#E9C893'
  },

          <TextInput
            ellipsizeMode="tail"
            numberOfLines={1}
            style={autocompleteStyle.textInput}
            underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
            onChangeText={text => props.onChangeText(text)}
            onContentSizeChange={event => {
              autocompleteInputHeight = getHeight(
                event.nativeEvent.contentSize.height
              )
            }}
            placeholder={props.placeholder}
            placeholderTextColor="#7c6a4d"
            value={props.value}
          />
```

Why is the text wrapping? It looks unprofessional because when it wraps it isn't vertically aligned

Comment: I had a similar problem with hyphenation on `-`, the problem was `lineHeight ` property. I removed it and then the text didn't wrap.